# When is touchmove actually fired?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My initial assumption was that `touchmove` was fired on every pixel move, but in my tests it varies depending on the speed of the movement. Is there a defined specification for it's behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `touchmove` event is part of the [W3C touch events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchmove-event), which says:

> Note that the rate at which the user agent sends touchmove events is implementation-defined, and may depend on hardware capabilities and other implementation details.

Comment: In terms of `TouchEvents` implementation, [here is a useful overview](http://patrickhlauke.github.io/touch/tests/results/#mobile-tablet-touchscreen-events) of the inconsistency between devices and/or browsers, with a `touchmove` reference in the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Touch events happen in this order.

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend
- then a delay...
- mmouseover
- mousemove
- mousedown
- mouseup
- click
- mouseout

Src: Bill Fisher @hotstudios

They have also developed a plugin called touchy that lets you control the touch events.
https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy

Comment: I think the OP is asking more about whether the touchmove event fires during, or at the end of, a drag.